# How do I create several df's out of one original df based on a condition and then assign them individual names

Tags: python, pandas

```
df_collection = {}
for country in country_names:
   df_collection[country] = df.loc[df['CountryName'] == country].copy
```

I want to create several df's (about 70 for each country one) out of one original df (each country is differing in frequency) and then assign them individual names (therefore I used a dictionary). But I can't access the individual df anymore. They should have different names and should remain a data frame.
error: 'method' object is not subscriptable

Does anyone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You assigned a method to each of your dictionary keys. You need to call copy with `()`, i.e. `df.loc[df['CountryName'] == country].copy()`.

However there's no need to subset your DataFrame in a loop. This is exactly what `groupby` is made for and you can create the dict succinctly with

```
df_collection = dict(tuple(df.groupby('CountryName')))
```

This works because the `__iter__` method of a groupby object: "Returns: Generator yielding sequence of (name, subsetted object) for each group" so with a single grouping key, those values become the keys of your dictionary.

#### Sample

```
print(df)
#  CountryName  Data
#0           a     8
#1           c     4
#2           b     4
#3           a     1
#4           a     1
#5           c     7

df_collection = dict(tuple(df.groupby('CountryName')))
## If you care for the subset defined in some list `country_names`, subset first
# df_collection = dict(tuple(df[df.CountryName.isin(country_names)].groupby('CountryName')))

df_collection['a']
#  CountryName  Data
#0           a     8
#3           a     1
#4           a     1
```

Comment: why do you use the function tuple, what problem does it prevent?

Comment: @YvesBoutellier Though the `groupby` object is iterable, it also satisfies the conditions of a mapping, so without calling `tuple` the `dict` method tries to create the dict in a way that it shouldn't as mappings take precedence over iterables